# ¿Qué parametros recibe QGIS en su controlador de protocolos?

Tags: windows

Intento que la aplicación QGIS permita ser ejecutada desde el navegador, por lo que he visto esta implementación no la trae consigo QGIS así que decidí intentar por mi cuenta esta funcionalidad.
Para ésto utilicé el editor de registros de windows para crear mi pripio URL protocol Handler y este lo hice con base a un regsitro que QGIS ya instala por defecto en el sistema operativo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que aparece como **QGIS Project** es un registro que viene con QGIS, este registro ejecuta la aplicación y recibe como paramatro un string.

Lo que yo hice para que ejecutase desde el navegador es duplicar este mismo registro pero indicandole que será un protocolo de URL (como se muestra en la siguiente imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto en realidad hace lo que necesito ejecutar la aplicación llamándola desde el navegador y hasta ahí todo Ok, el problema está en que al parecer el parametro que recibe es un **Data source** o según la aplicación lo dice

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado de muchas maneras, enviando tanto Json como string o pasándole URL's y no he logrado descifrar que realmente debe enviarse por ese parametro, he intentado leer la documentación pero no he logrado conseguir nada útil.

¿Saben a qué tipo de Data Source hace referencia?

Comment: Si le pasas como parametro un path de algun archivo .qgz este lo acepta pero no lo abre, el anterior error mencionado deja de aparecer pero muestra un warning WARNING    Error zip file does not exist